# Like item in VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook, vb-like-operator

I was wondering if there is something like a "Like" in VBA for Outlook 2003/2007 just like the LIKE in SQL...

For Example you have multiple users in a Network and everyone has another Mailbox name.

So i was thinking about something like this:

```
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set TopFolder = olNs.Folders.Item("Mailbox - *") '<----- here i was thinking of something like a LIKE
Set SubFolder = TopFolder.Folders.Item("Projekte")
Set Folder = SubFolder.Folders
```

Thanks for Help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `LIKE` in VBA for string pattern matching, but to use in in your scenario you would need to iterate over the names of items in the `olNs.Folders` collection and compare them with your pattern;

```
if sFolderName like "Mailbox - *" then 
   Set TopFolder = olNs.Folders.Item(sFolderName) 
   exit for
   ...
```